# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Login)"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to set up redux on a personal project I've been working on for a while, but I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error: 
`Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Login)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Login) in connect options.`

I made sure that I have provider with a store, I've tried changing how my store is created and have moved around my routing a bit to no success. Here is my code

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <Router history={history}>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Nav/>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Login.js

```
export default connect(
    state => {
        return {auth: state.auth}
    },
    (dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
))(Login);
```

configStore.js

```
export default function configureStore(history, initialState) {
    const reducers = {
        auth: Auth.reducer
    };

    const middleware = [
        thunk,
        routerMiddleware(history)
    ];

    // In development, use the browser's Redux dev tools extension if installed
    const enhancers = [];
    const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
    if (isDevelopment && typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__) {
        enhancers.push(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
    }

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        ...reducers,
        routing: routerReducer
    });

    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
    );
}
```

Auth.js

```
const setAuth = 'SET_AUTH';
const removeAuth = 'REMOVE_AUTH';
const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false
};

export const actionCreators = {
    setAuthInfo: (authInfo) => ({type: setAuth, ...authInfo}),
    removeAuthInfo: () => ({type: removeAuth})
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    state = state || initialState;

    if (action.type === setAuth) {
        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: action.isAuthenticated
        }
    }

    if (action.type === removeAuth) {
        return {
            ...initialState
        }
    }

    return state;
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^1.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "firebase": "^6.2.4",
    "history": "latest",
    "npm-watch": "^0.6.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.17",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.7.0",
    "react-image": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwind": "^4.0.0",
    "watch": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "tailwindcss": "postcss src/assets/css/tailwind.src.css -o src/assets/css/tailwind.css",
    "watch-tailwindcss": "npm run tailwindcss --watch",
    "start": "npm run tailwindcss && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run tailwindcss && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "watch": "npm-watch"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "watch": {
    "build:copy": {
      "patterns": [
        "src"
      ],
      "extensions": "js,jsx,html,css"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't get why I am getting told to wrap the whole thing with a `<Provider>` when I already have and I am not using a context provider so that shouldn't matter. It shouldn't be giving me an error from what I can tell.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you create the store?

Comment: @mgarcia I updated it with the files I have for the store.

Comment: Where's your routerReducer coming from?

Comment: It is coming from 'react-router-redux',

Comment: @harriskasher, can you provide your _package.json_ file so that we can take into account the versions of the different libraries you are using?

Comment: @mgarcia I added the package.json file.

Comment: Mmmm, it seems the package [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) is deprecated. In the page, it recommends to use [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) for React Router 4+.

Comment: I got the same problem as I use npm test from Jest, the APP seems no problem but for test, it's showing this issue. Still not figure out the solution cause I already have  either wrappe <Provider> in root App.js